# Is there any way to catch an event fired within another contract which is called by low level 'call' opcode from main contract in solidity

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have a Multisig contract that when reaches the minimum quorum, it can execute a low level call Transaction which may be held on another contract.

```
function _execute(Transaction storage transaction) internal {
    //some code

    // solhint-disable-next-line
    (bool success, ) = transaction.target.call{value: transaction.value}(callData); // FIRES AN EVENT IN OTHER CONTRACT

    if (success) {
        emit TransactionExecuted( // FIRES SECOND
            //some code
        );
    } else {
        emit TransactionFailed(
            //some code
        );
    //some code
    }
}
```

My execute function fires an event after execution of the Transaction (call) whether it was successful or not, in the meanwhile if call function request has an event to fire, I can catch the event fired by the contract, but event parameters are not there, The second contract which is called by _execute() is written as follows:

```
function _addMember(
    address memberAddress,
    bytes32 memberName,
    Membership _membership
)
    internal
{
    //some code
    
    // Fire an event
    emit MembershipChanged(memberAddress, true, _membership); // FIRES FIRST
}
```

The following is the test written in typescript, I can get the event fired on called contract, but there is no data in it

```
it("should contain two events from previous transaction, adding a new core member and running a Transaction by multisig", async () => {
    //r is the receipt of the caller (multisig) contract
    expect(r.events!.length).to.be.eq(2); // MembershipChanged, TransactionExecuted
    
    //NOTE: r.events![0].address === memberReg.address // memReg is the callee contract
    
    /*THE FOLLOWING DOESN'T CONTAIN EVENT DATA NOR TOPICS OF memReg CONTRACT*/
    expect(r.events![0].event).to.be.eq("MembershipChanged"); //faild
    expect(r.events![0].args!.member).to.be.eq(coreCandidateAddr) //faild
    expect(r.events![0].args!.isMember).to.be.true; //fails
    expect(r.events![0].args!.membership).to.be.eq(Membership.Core); //faild

    /* THE FOLLOWING WORKS WELL */
    expect(r.events![1].event).to.be.eq("TransactionExecuted"); //passed
    //some code
  })
```

I guess it would be possible to catch those events in production easily by listening to that deployed contract, but I don't know how to do this in test environment

Comment: You can scrape it directly from the chain, using `await yourContractInstance.getPastEvents(eventName, {fromBlock: fromBlock, toBlock: toBlock})`. This is how you could do it using web3.js. HardHat uses ethers.js, so there might be a slightly different syntax for that.

Comment: And if you omit `toBlock`, then it will run until the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Thanks to @bbbbbbbbb here is the simple solution, it should listen on before the transaction call

```
memberReg.once("MembershipChanged", (member, isMember, membership, event) => {
    expect(event.event).to.be.eq("MembershipChanged"); //passed
    expect(member).to.be.eq(coreCandidateAddr); //passed
    expect(isMember).to.be.true; //passed
    expect(membership).to.be.eq(Membership.Core); //passed
});

r = await awaitTx(multisig.execute(id)); // execution happens here
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your functions _execute and _addMember are marked as internal, it should be mark as external or public to be called in testing environment, or create a public function that call it.
2. If you are using hardhat the easy way is using the testing pattern for events suggested by hardhat documentation, this also works for low level calls.

   ```
    const tx = await YourContract.execute(foo);

    //Check that the event fired by a low level call is correct
    //withArgs receive the expected values for the event 

    expect(tx).to.emit(YourContract, "MembershipChanged").withArgs(foo, bar...);
   ```

   For more info check the implementation for hardhat docs: https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts#full-coverage

Comment: Dear David, I am calling them with external functions, I just didn't include that part of the code here.